# Calling the super keyword from constructor to interface implemented

Tags: java, android, super

I was wondering that what happens if we call `super()` in the constructor of a class that implements an interface. For example with the `Serializable` interface:

```
public class ToDoItem implements Serializable {

    private long id;
    private String todoString;
    private long date;
    private String place;

    private String authorEmailId;

    public ToDoItem() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would call constructor of `Object` class. All classes are implicitly extended from `Object` if none is specified.

Comment: is there anything happen to the interface?

Comment: No, in java  interfaces don't have any method/function definitions. Plus, the super called from constructor invokes the parent class's constructor, which in your case, you dont have any explicit class as parent. So, calling super here is not really doing anything.

Comment: If you *don't* call `super()`, the call is inserted for you automatically.